# How to unpivot multiple colums to rows in Bigquery sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm struggling to unpivot/pivot using SQL.

I tried UNPIVOT function from BIGQUERY documentation but I succeded to unpivot only ONE colums by using the code below but not multiple at the same time

```
SELECT ... FROM
UNPIVOT(mail_sent FOR metric IN (mail_sent))
```

Here is the table I've got

| month | mail_sent | mail_received | mail_opened |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2000 | 1900 | 500 |
| 02 | 2200 | 2000 | 700 |
| 03 | 1900 | 1800 | 400 |

Here is what I want to have, keep the **month** in colums and have ALL the rest in rows :

| values | 01 | 02 | 03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mail_sent | 2000 | 2200 | 1900 |
| mail_received | 1900 | 2000 | 1800 |
| mail_opened | 500 | 700 | 400 |

Any idea of how to do it ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```sql
SELECT month, metric, value
  FROM final 
  UNPIVOT(value FOR metric IN (mail_sent, mail_received, mail_opened))
  ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select * from your_table 
  unpivot(value for metric in (mail_sent, mail_received, mail_opened))
)
pivot (any_value(value) as _ for month in ('01', '02', '03'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]